# How to make dynamic height based on text size?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create custom view which looks like this: [image]

I can set the height of the container, but in this case it won't adjust when the text is resized. So, I have to use `wrapContentHeight()`, but in this case I don't know how to set the height of the first four boxes so that their height is the same as the last one.

Comment: check out [Intrinsic measurements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov thanks! Intrinsic measurements work for this case